# Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference usando PDO like

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa no BD onde os parâmetros são passados e uso o LIKE para pesquisar, só que a pesquisa me retorna o erro PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

```
$this->Query = $this->Conn->prepare('select * '.
                                    'from tabela '.
                                    'inner join tabela2 on tabela.pr_status = prstatus.prstatus_status '.
                                    'where :tableColumn like :inputSearchProtocol'
                                    );  
$this->Query->bindParam(':tableColumn'          ,$this->tableColumn);
$this->Query->bindParam(':inputSearchProtocol'  ,'%'.$this->inputSearchProtocol.'%');
```

O erro no servidor aponta para a linha com o campo '%'.$this->inputSearchProtocol.'%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `bindParam()` recebe os parâmetros por referência, por isso você não pode usar literais, apenas variáveis.

Usando variável, fica assim:

```
$variavel = '%'.$this->inputSearchProtocol.'%';
$this->Query->bindParam(':inputSearchProtocol', $variavel);
```

Mas, provavelmente, é muito mais simples usar `bindValue`:

```
$this->Query->bindValue(':inputSearchProtocol'  ,'%'.$this->inputSearchProtocol.'%');
```

Manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php